# Is there xaml code to mute CEFSharp browser?

Tags: wpf, xaml, cefsharp

I can't seem to find any reference to determine if there is a way to mute CEFSharp browser in xaml. Does anyone know if this is possible? Something like;

<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" MuteAudio="true"/> Intellisense seems to say not but...any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You can mute the browser,  just not currently from xaml.

Comment: Do wish to permanently mute all browsers or selectively toggle mute at runtime?

Comment: @amaitland  - selectively toggle. I have two instances concurrently running and want  only one to be muted. I did use the cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("mute-audio") but as you know that mutes all browsers.

Comment: Programatically You can call http://cefsharp.github.io/api/92.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_SetAudioMuted.htm You can get an IBrowserHost instance from your ChromiumWebBrowser instance using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/92.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_GetBrowserHost.htm from memory you should be able to create an attached property if you need to expose the functionality in xaml

Comment: @amaitland Thank you . Although now I am having some difficulty getting your suggestion working - most likely due to my inexperience. I'll start another thread/question for that though.

Comment: Edit your question and provide an example of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @maitland Thanks again, I got it to work. Cheers.